# How to remove subdomain from char value c

Tags: c

I have a char value sometimes it is domain.com which is fine or it can be www.domain.com  or host222.site1.domain.com

no matter what i want to phrase the char so it always strips to domain.com
so like anything infront of domain.com if it is just www. or xx.xx.x.x.domain.com it still strips

so i got

```
void phrase3(char *buffer) {
char foo[4096];
    int len;

const char *p;


p = strchr(buffer, '.');


if (p && p > buffer) {
    int offset = p - buffer + 1;
    int len = strlen(buffer);

    memmove(buffer, buffer + offset, len - offset + 1);
}

    return;
}
```

Comment: and what is your question? What did not work with the code above?

Comment: You'll only need to specify how many dots in the required strip-down. So the algorithm can also handle `domain.co.uk`

Comment: yeah sometimes it is host222.site.domain.com i just need domain.com or it can be user33.site.co.uk  then i just need site.co.uk

Comment: above works fine if just www.domain.com then it work fine

Answer (score 1):

This is inspired by cleblanc's answer. It also takes into consideration those domains that end in country code.

```
const char *getDomain(const char * const website) {
    char *p=website;
    while(*p) p++;
    do {
        p--;
    } while (*p != '.' && p > website);
    if(strlen(p) < 4)
        do {
            p--;
        } while (*p != '.' && p > website);
    do {
        p--;
    } while (*p != '.' && p > website);
    return (p>website?p+1:website);
}
```

The function will not modify the string parameter. The function will return a pointer to the same string where the domain name starts. It avoids using string functions except strlen(p) which can be easily substituted by counting the characters in p up to the null byte.

The first while loop moves p to the end of the string.

The second while loop gets the last `.` in the domain name. This is equivalent to `strrchr(p,'.')`.

The if condition checks if the domain suffix is a country code, which means it will have to be 3 domain layers, hence the while loop inside.

The last while loop gets the outermost needed `.`. Finally, if the pointer is within the original string, return the pointed location past the `.`. If not, just return the original location of the string.

Sample output.

```
$ /tmp/getDomain 127.0.0.1.site-01.anotesite.realsite.com
Domain: realsite.com

$ /tmp/getDomain test.xx.xx.yyy.sales.co.uk
Domain: sales.co.uk
```

Answer (score 0):

Try counting backwards from the end of the string.  Seemingly the requirement is that the output will have at most one '.' character.

```
void phrase3(char * buffer, int numDots)
{
  char * p = NULL;
  int count = 0;

  numDots++;
  if (buffer != NULL)
  {
    p = buffer + strlen(buffer);

    while ((p > buffer) && (count < numDots))
    {
      if (*p == '.')
         count++;
      p--;
    }
    if (count == numDots) 
    {
      p+=2;
      sprintf(buffer, "%s", p);
    }
  }
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
  phrase3(argv[1], strtol(argv[2]));
  printf("%s\n", argv[1]);
}


c:\eng\golf>a.exe 127.0.0.1.site-01.anotesite.realsite.com 5
a.exe 127.0.0.1.site-01.anotesite.realsite.com 5
0.1.site-01.anotesite.realsite.com

c:\eng\golf>a.exe 127.0.0.1.site-01.anotesite.realsite.com 0
a.exe 127.0.0.1.site-01.anotesite.realsite.com 0
com

c:\eng\golf>a.exe 127.0.0.1.site-01.anotesite.realsite.com 1
a.exe 127.0.0.1.site-01.anotesite.realsite.com 1
realsite.com

c:\eng\golf>a.exe 127.0.0.1.site-01.anotesite.realsite.com 2
a.exe 127.0.0.1.site-01.anotesite.realsite.com 2
anotesite.realsite.com

c:\eng\golf>a.exe 127.0.0.1.site-01.anotesite.realsite.com 3
a.exe 127.0.0.1.site-01.anotesite.realsite.com 3
site-01.anotesite.realsite.com
```

This one seemed to work for me.

Comment: You will need to move your test `count == numDots` inside your `while` loop and act accordingly. Try testing `www.domain.com` or `xx.xx.x.x.domain.com` with your function....

Comment: i get seg fault  with 127.0.0.1.site-01.anotesite.realsite.com

Comment: @Hans I think you must be passing a `const` character string to this function, and since the function is modifying the string that's passed in you get a seg fault.  I didn't change the signature of his phrase3 to return a new string so I assumed we needed to modify the string.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of approaches you can take depending on what you mean by always returning '*domain.com*'. If your intent is to return the last two components of any '*domain.tld*' regardless of what the actual name is, then you can do something simple like the following. It simply finds the last `'.'` and works backwards to locate any preceding `'.'` or beginning of the string:

```
/* return last two components of URL for a string ending with URL
 * if 'fqdn' is a valid url with at least the form 'domain.tld',
 * on success return 'domain.tld' from any string 'stuff.domain.tld',
 * otherwise return NULL.
 */
char *getdomain (const char *fqdn)
{
    char *p = strrchr (fqdn, '.');  /* last '.' in fqdn */
    if (!p) return NULL;
    size_t idx = 0;

    if (p - fqdn)               /* set index in fqdn    */
        idx = p - fqdn - 1;     /* to char before '.'   */
    else
        return NULL;

    while (idx--)               /* find next prev. '.'  */
        if (fqdn[idx] == '.')   /* return next char     */
            return (char *)(fqdn + idx + 1);

    return (char *)fqdn;
}
```

If on the other hand, your intent was to return only the `*domain.tld*` when the name is `"domain.com"`, then you can use a similar approach, but add a string compare at the end of the process. (**note:** this will also cover the first case as well by simply passing `token` as `NULL`):

```
/* return last two components of URL for a string ending with URL
 * if 'fqdn' is a valid url with at least the form 'domain.tld'.
 * if 'token' not NULL, compare 'token' with 'domain.tld' and
 * on match return 'domain.tld' from any string 'stuff.domain.tld',
 * otherwise return NULL.
 */
char *getnameddomain (const char *fqdn, const char *token)
{
    char *p = NULL;
    char *domain = NULL;
    size_t idx = 0;

    p = strrchr (fqdn, '.');    /* locate last '.' in fqdn  */
    if (!p) return NULL;        /* invalid url, return      */

    if (p - fqdn)               /* set index in fqdn for    */
        idx = p - fqdn - 1;     /* char prior to '.'        */
    else
        return NULL;

    while (idx--)               /* find next prev. '.' char */
        if (fqdn[idx] == '.') { /* if '.', set domain (+1)  */
            domain = (char *)(fqdn + idx + 1);
            break;
        }

    if (!domain) domain = (char *)fqdn;  /* 2-part url only */

    if (token && strcmp (domain, token)) /* if tok, compare */
        return NULL;

    return domain;
}
```

**Note:** both functions simply return a pointer to the beginning of the substring within the original `fqdn`. If you need a separate string, be sure to copy to a new address.

A short example that would exercise both functions (cheesily borrowing the array from WeatherVane `:)`) could be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *getdomain (const char *fqdn);
char *getnameddomain (const char *fqdn, const char *token);

int main (void) {

    char *example[] = { 
        "domain.com",
        "www.domain.com", 
        "xx.xx.x.x.domain.com", 
        "http://www.xx.xx.x.x.domain.com", 
        "www.domain.co.uk",
        "a.com",
        ".com",
        "ischkabibble"
    };
    size_t i;

    /* using getdomain() */
    printf ("\nAll domains: - getdomain()\n\n");
    for (i = 0; i < (size_t)(sizeof example / sizeof *example); i++)
        printf (" %s --> %s\n", example[i], getdomain (example[i]));

    /* using getnameddomain() */
    printf ("\nAll domains matching 'domain.com':\n\n");
    for (i = 0; i < (size_t)(sizeof example / sizeof *example); i++)
        printf (" %s --> %s\n", example[i], getnameddomain (example[i],
                "domain.com"));

    printf ("\nAll domains - getnameddomain():\n\n");
    for (i = 0; i < (size_t)(sizeof example / sizeof *example); i++)
        printf (" %s --> %s\n", example[i], getnameddomain (example[i], NULL));

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
$ ./bin/getdomain

All domains: - getdomain()

 domain.com --> domain.com
 www.domain.com --> domain.com
 xx.xx.x.x.domain.com --> domain.com
 http://www.xx.xx.x.x.domain.com --> domain.com
 www.domain.co.uk --> co.uk
 a.com --> a.com
 .com --> (null)
 ischkabibble --> (null)

All domains matching 'domain.com':

 domain.com --> domain.com
 www.domain.com --> domain.com
 xx.xx.x.x.domain.com --> domain.com
 http://www.xx.xx.x.x.domain.com --> domain.com
 www.domain.co.uk --> (null)
 a.com --> (null)
 .com --> (null)
 ischkabibble --> (null)

All domains - getnameddomain():

 domain.com --> domain.com
 www.domain.com --> domain.com
 xx.xx.x.x.domain.com --> domain.com
 http://www.xx.xx.x.x.domain.com --> domain.com
 www.domain.co.uk --> co.uk
 a.com --> a.com
 .com --> (null)
 ischkabibble --> (null)
```

Comment: hi domain.com can be anything xxx.com yy.com etc

Comment: so we dont know the root domain we just get the char and need phrase(char) and then it clean all from *.anydomain.*    can be asdasd.net saoihjiod.co.uk anything.com etc.

Comment: Right, using either function, `saoihjiod.co.uk` would return `co.uk` (with `token` set to `NULL` or to enforce only `co.uk` set to `"co.uk"`). I'll add additional descriptions to the funcitons

Answer (score 0):

This is what i use. It allocates further memory, doesn't work in-place.

```
char * strip(char *input)
{
    char *retval = NULL;
    char *str = strdup(input);
    char *p = strtok(str, ".");
    char *p_prev = NULL;
    char *p_cur = NULL;
    while (p)
    {
        p_prev = p_cur;
        p_cur = p;
        p = strtok(NULL, ".");
    }
    if (p_prev)
    {
        if (retval = malloc(strlen(p_prev) + strlen(p_cur) + 2))
        {
            strcpy(retval, p_prev);
            strcat(retval, ".");
            strcat(retval, p_cur);
        }
    }
    free(str);
    return retval;
}
```

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin which line are you talking about specifically? I couldn't see any memory leak, apart from the fact that caller should free the memory, which is not shown here.

Comment: I apologize -- I missed that your `if (prev)` was outside your `while` -- no leak.